# WebRequest.Proxy - What is the default value

Tags: c#, .net

Background: We have a service installed at a remote site that has started failing to call an external webservice. According to the network\support engineers on site no proxy should be required, but when attempting to execute the WebRequest an exception is returned:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
```

The exception is relatively self-explanatory, but looking at the code, no Proxy is specified in the call to the WebRequest and no proxy is defined in the app.config file.

Referring to the MSDN documentation for WebRequest.Proxy:

*"The IWebProxy object to use to proxy the request. The default value is set by calling the GlobalProxySelection.Select property."*

and then referring to the documentation for GlobalProxySelection.Select:

*"Gets or sets the global HTTP proxy."*

And given that GlobalProxySelection.Select is not set anywhere in the application, where does the default value come from? And are there any other global config files where the global HTTP proxy may be set?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the proxy manually.  You can do it by doing the following, if you want to use the Default system proxy.  (Internet settings in windows)

`myRequest.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();`

You are getting the error because your network is blocking access to the server directly without using a proxy.

Comment: But the point is I don't want to use a proxy at all. But it seems to be defaulting to a proxy for some reason and I can't find where or why it's trying to use a proxy.

Comment: Check your windows networking settings or Check with your systems administrator if you are on a office network.  Are all your internet connections going through a proxy?

Comment: The system administrators say there is a rule in place such that the call to this particular web service should require no proxy; and indeed if I turn off the proxy in IE and browse to the web service it loads as expected. In the C# service no proxy is set in the code, none is set in app.config and none is set in machine.config.  So I'm confused as to why it's trying to use a proxy.

Comment: Are you running any "special" software on Windows that transparently uses proxy for all other applications.  I used to have something at the place I worked before called Microsoft ISA Web client.  That transparently pushed everything through a proxy and had to be disabled.

Comment: I don't run anything; it's on a production server managed by someone else :)  I don't see anything like that on the server in question though. Ignoring for now software like that, my basic question still stands: what is the default behaviour of the .NET framework when no proxy is specified? i.e. If in my code and the app.config\machine.config files no proxy is set, would the .NET framework default to use no proxy?

Comment: @mutex your `WebRequest` will inherit the proxy settings from IE/Windows. On the remote site machine what are the proxy settings?

Comment: @wal: We tested that but get the same behaviour with and without a proxy specified in IE connection settings, so it appears to be getting it from somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't solve your problem directly, can I recommend trying a `<defaultProxy />` element in your app.config / web.config under `<system.net>` with `useDefaultCredentials="true"` - this may well get your application authenticating through the proxy and therefore not requiring a special bypass rule at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```